# How to assign value to a @html.validationfor id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.name, "", new { id = "valName" })
```

I need to assign value for "valName" using JavaScript or jQuery.

Is there any way to assign value to the id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear exactly what you want to do?

If you want to change the `id` of the validation message DOM element:

```
document.getElementById('valName').id = 'newId';

// or via jQuery
$('#valName').attr('id', 'newId');
```

If you want to change the `text` of the validation message DOM element:

```
document.getElementById('valName').innerHTML = 'new content';

// or via jQuery
$('#valName').html('new content');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[class^=field-validation]').each(function () {
        var id = "val" + $(this).attr("data-valmsg-for");
        $(this).attr("id", id);
    });
});
```

It will set the id to the same as the form field but prefixed with "val".